# GCP image creation from a compressed RAW image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When an image is created from a compressed RAW image stored in a gcs bucket, is an instance spun up in the background to validate the image? I would like to understand how the image creation process works and if Google adds some software on top of what's in the RAW image.

Answer (score 0):

According to our [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image#overview) regarding the importation of Boot Disk Images to Compute Engine. In the overview section, we explain all the needed steps to understand how the image creating process works. This will reply to your question “I would like to understand how the image creation process works”.

Verifying this steps details will allow you to address the remaining questions and you’ll know that we don’t spin up an instance in the background to validate the image and that Google doesn’t add any software on top of what’s in the RAW image.

Customers are responsible for: 
1- Planning for the import path
2- Preparing the boot disk so it can boot in Compute Engine environment
3- Creating and compressing the boot disk 
4- Uploading the image 
5- Using the imported image to create a VM